# Have timelineMax wait for an event, while looping it infinitely

Tags: gsap

How can I have a timeline, to loop a tweenmax animation infinitely, till an event is fired, then moved on to the next tween?

```
timeline = new TimelineMax();
timeline.append(TweenMax.to(targetReel, .3, {y: -(Main.iconH >> 1)}));

//keep spinning infinitely. Not firing the onComplete function till I got a result
timeline.append(TweenMax.to(targetReel, 2, {y: newNumber, ease: Linear.easeNone, onComplete: somefunction}));

//got a result/dispatch event, continue timeline
timeline.append(TweenMax.to(targetReel, 1 + (i * .6), {y: 0, ease: Back.easeOut, onStart: somefunction, onComplete: endAnimation}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in a function and you can use it without using timeline and have some event change repeating to false

```
    var repeating = true;
    TweenMax.to(targetReel, .3, {y: -(Main.iconH >> 1)},onComplete: repeat);

    function repeat(){
        if (repeating){
            //keep spinning infinitely. Not firing the onComplete function till I got a result
            TweenMax.to(targetReel, 2, {delay: .3, y: newNumber, ease: Linear.easeNone, onComplete: repeat});
        }else{ // repeating == false
            TweenMax.to(targetReel, 2, {y: newNumber, ease: Linear.easeNone, onComplete: doneRepeating});
        }
    }

    function doneRepeating(){
        //got a result/dispatch event, continue timeline
        TweenMax.to(targetReel, 1 + (i * .6), {y: 0, ease: Back.easeOut, onStart: somefunction, onComplete: endAnimation});
    }


    // have some event change repeating to false;
```